# Write to file from PostgreSQL C function

Tags: c, postgresql, function

I need to write some information from postgres to an external file. I've tried to achieve this goal like in the following code:

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include <stdio.h>


PG_MODULE_MAGIC;

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(write_note);
Datum write_note(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
   float8 v = PG_GETARG_FLOAT8(0);
   char const *file_path = "d:/notes/note_0.txt";
   FILE *f_pt;
   f_pt = fopen(file_path,"w"); 
   fprintf(f_pt, "The inserted value was: %f", v);
   fclose (f_pt);

   PG_RETURN_FLOAT8(v);
}
```

Then I've compiled it in shared object and created a C function in postgres:

```
   CREATE FUNCTION write_note(double precision) RETURNS double precision
   AS '<-----path to the file------->/write_note.so', 'write_note'
   LANGUAGE C STRICT;
```

When I try to call this function like this: SELECT write_note(2.71828); following message appears: "The application has lost the database connection".
Please help to understand what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: One thing you are doing wrong (maybe not **the** thing) is you did not check to see of the fopen succeeded.   Also, look in the server's log file to see if there is a better message.

Comment: jjanes, as you rightly pointed out, I should verify if(f_pt == NULL) to output relative note to stderr and terminate the function,I tried that in way but nothing changed. What regards the log, it says following: 
```The application has lost the database connection:
⁃ If the connection was idle it may have been forcibly disconnected.
⁃ The application server or database server may have been restarted.
⁃ The user session may have timed out.
```
and I have not very clear idea how to interpret that in this particular case.

Comment: The is the application server log.  Look in the PostgreSQL server log.

Comment: In the makefile the INCLUDEPATH was left to point to older version of libraries installed on the same machine. I corrected it and now it works!